# изменение значения одного селекта значением другого селекта в цикле

Tags: html, css, jquery, циклы, класс

Две цены формируются к каждому товару следующими кодами-

```html
1-й товар
<span class="changeprice" style="cursor:pointer;">change_price</span>
<input id="" class="change_price"  type="text" name="price[{$v->id}]" value="{$v->price}"></span>
<input id="" class="prprice" type=text name=purchases[price][{$purchase->id}] value='{$purchase->price}' size=5>
2-й товар
<span class="changeprice" style="cursor:pointer;">change_price</span>
<input id="" class="change_price"  type="text" name="price[{$v->id}]" value="{$v->price}"></span>
<input id="" class="prprice" type=text name=purchases[price][{$purchase->id}] value='{$purchase->price}' size=5>
3-й товар
<span class="changeprice" style="cursor:pointer;">change_price</span>
<input id="" class="change_price"  type="text" name="price[{$v->id}]" value="{$v->price}"></span>
<input id="" class="prprice" type=text name=purchases[price][{$purchase->id}] value='{$purchase->price}' size=5>
```

Пытаюсь кодом поменять цену на всех товарах но меняет по последней цене все три.

```html
$(".changeprice").click(function(){
    $('.prprice').each(function(index,value) {
        var val = $(this).val();
    $('.change_price').each(function(index,value) {
    $('.change_price').val(val)
      });
    });
    $("#order").submit();
});
```

пока писал, вглянул со стороны и придумал такой способ, но он возвращает только последнее значение.

```js
$(".changeprice").click(function(){
    $("input[name = 'price[{/literal}{$v->id}{literal}]']").val($("input[name= 'purchases[price][{/literal}{$purchase->id}{literal}]']").val());
    $("#order").submit();
});
```

Подскажите, что не так делаю.